# Adding library function for sorting array gives undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add a Library function for sorting Items in an array. Though I got link and way, but when trying to make a library function, this doesn't work. can someone help me out as it is responding `undefined` as result.

```js
var arr1 = [5, 4, 2, 6, 9, 2, 8, 1, 6];

Array.prototype.sortItems = function(){
  this.sort((a,b) => a - b);
}

console.log(arr1.sortItems());
```

**Reference:**

[image]
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: The solution is in the link you've added: _"Return value: The sorted array. Note that the array is sorted in place, and no copy is made."_

Comment: How do you want `log` a result without `return`  from your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return the result of `this.sort()`

```js
var arr1 = [5, 4, 2, 6, 9, 2, 8, 1, 6];

Array.prototype.sortItems = function(){
  return this.sort((a,b) => a - b);
}

console.log(arr1.sortItems());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the result

```js
var arr1 = [5, 4, 2, 6, 9, 2, 8, 1, 6];

Array.prototype.sortItems = function(){
  return this.sort((a,b) => a - b);
}

console.log(arr1.sortItems());
```

FYI, `compareFunction` is optional

```js
var arr1 = [5, 4, 2, 6, 9, 2, 8, 1, 6];

console.log(arr1.sort());
```

Comment: yes 'compare function' is optional, but without it data like [5,4,2,1,100,57...] won't work! So, for proper working, its required!